# Count in document used source references

Tags: bibtex, statistics

I currently gathering some statistical information about my thesis for reporting purposes. One metric I want to determine is how many sources I have referenced.
I have a BibTeX file with more than 150 sources, but I only use a subset in my thesis. Is there a way to count the used sources (the sources in the source-index, not the `\cite` commands). I don't use a number based short reference and I don't want to change my citation style.

Is there a count-macro or something else to count referenced sources in LaTeX?

Comment: The [`checkcites`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites) script does what you want. It's in TeX Live 2011.

Comment: How about `grep '\\bibitem ' jobname.bbl | wc -l`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an uptodate TeX Live 2011, the `checkcites` script from the command line does what you want. If your main file is called `myfile.tex`, compile it as usual and run `bibtex`. Then

```
checkcites myfile.aux
```

will tell you how many entries you have explicitly called and how many have not been referenced (`\nocite{*}` will not count them).

Comment: is there an equivalent in miktex?

Comment: @martin Sorry, no; I don't know why MiKTeX doesn't install it. However, you can download the script `checkcites.lua` and execute it with `texlua checkcites.lua myfile.aux` from a DOS shell.

Comment: @martin Adding anything executable is slightly more work than adding simple packages, so Christian Schenk (MiKTeX author) may take a little while to add it. You'd be best to ask him directly about this!

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this new package in comp.text.tex: [lastbib](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lastbib).