# Count the number of references containing substring in field

Tags: biblatex, counters, xstring

I have several references in a document. I'd like to display some statistics regarding the references - for example,

- citations with author `Smith`,
- citations between year `xxxx` and `yyyy`,
- citations published in Journal `foo`,
- citations not published in a journal (I think that I only have `@inproceedings` and `@book` types).

I'm using `biblatex`.

There are several questions about counting the *total* number of citations used: for example, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61921/count-in-document-used-source-references), and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66829/count-number-of-references-using-biblatex). These are similar to what I want to do, but the answers aren't extensible to my use-case.

From [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66868/13835), I can count the citations published between two years using:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtDataInput{
    \ifboolexpr{ test { \ifnumless  {\thefield{year}+0}{2005}} and
                 test {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}+0}{2000}}}
                 { \stepcounter{c_years} }{}
 {}
}
```

I'm trying to do something similar to count the authors with name `Smith` and publications in journal `foo`:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcounter{c_foo}
\AtDataInput{
    \IfSubStr{\strfield{booktitle}}{foo}{ \stepcounter{c_foo} }{}
 {}
}
```

I step a counter if `foo` is a substring of `\strfield{booktitle}`. However, this doesn't work (the counter remains at 0). I've tried with `\thefield`, which also doesn't work.

I thought perhaps `foo` wasn't surrounded by whitespace, and that xstrings `\IfSubStr` wasn't picking it up, but these both work:

```
\IfSubStr{The foo bear}{foo}{ \stepcounter{c_foo} }{}
\IfSubStr{Thefoobear}{foo}{ \stepcounter{c_foo_two} }{}
```

I'm taking this approach because when it works, I should be able to check for substrings of any of the fields, which is an extensible solution.

#### How can I increment a counter if `foo` is a substring of one of the fields of my references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem of category codes. The string returned by `\strfield` is composed by category code 12 characters, which are not matched by the category code 11 ones you use in the search string.

Solution:

```
\IfSubStr{\strfield{booktitle}}{\detokenize{foo}}{\stepcounter{c_foo}}{}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks - I wouldn't have found that. For future viewers, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes) for more detail regarding TeX category codes.